# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, android, serialization, facebook-fql, gson

This is my first approach to serialization using Gson. I recive facebook response to my android application like this

My Json:

```
 {"data": [
    {
        "pic_square": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.netxxxx1388091435_797626998_q.jpg",
        "uid": "10202xxx852765",
        "name": "Mister X"
    },
    {
        "pic_square": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.netxxxx1388091435_797626998_q.jpg",
        "uid": "10202xxx852765",
        "name": "Mister X"
    }
   ]
}



    try {
       final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
       final Gson gson = builder.create();
       JSONObject data= response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();             
       FacebookResponses facebookResponses= gson.fromJson(data.toString(),FacebookResponses.class); //exception here
       Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + facebookResponses.toString());
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

} 
My class

```
public class FacebookResponses implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @SerializedName("data");
      private FacebookRisp[] data;
}

class FacebookRisp implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @SerializedName("pic_square")
   private String[] pic_square;

   @SerializedName("uid")
   private String[] uid;

   @SerializedName("name")
   private String[] name;

   public String[] getPic_square() {
        return pic_square;
   }

   public void setPic_square(String[] pic_square) {
    this.pic_square = pic_square;
   }

    public String[] getUid() {
    return uid;
   }

   public void setUid(String[] uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
   }

   public String[] getName() {
    return name;
   }

   public void setName(String[] name) {
    this.name = name;
   }

 }
```

I get 
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 118

UPDATE:
I modified the answer of aegean, the problem were **[]**

```
@SerializedName("pic_square")
private String**[]** pic_square;   //ex here and others
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `FacebookResponses` class to these:

```
private class FacebookResponses {
    private Data[] data;
}

private class Data {
    @SerializedName("pic_square")
    private String picSquare;
    private String uid;
    private String name;
}
```

**Edit:** Because your json response's structure is like below:

[image]

Comment: I edited my class like you can see above but i always get the same error :'(

Answer (score 1):

> [MalformedJsonException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/MalformedJsonException.html) Thrown when a reader encounters malformed JSON. Some syntax errors can be ignored by calling setLenient(boolean).

Its difficult to find solution but seems like that your JSON response is not valid. [Check here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I recive this response from facebook by fql. The online checher works if i put "data":[{"pic_square":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/xxx.jpg",
       "uid":"1020272xxxx852765","name":"Mister X"}  but how can extraxt automatically the right informations from the response?

Comment: try with some other testing parm ,or it could be possible that you are not calling that API properly.(mean number of param)

Comment: Ok I got it. now I have the right Json adding : JSONObject data= response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();        String dataString= data.toString(); but I get com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 118

Comment: update your response code in your question and "update" new things

Comment: I did. you can see above