# parse Json to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I have `Json` response like :

```
[
 {       
   "first_name": "fname1",
   "last_name": "lname1"
 },
 {
   "first_name": "fname2",
   "last_name": "lname2",
   "city_name": "paris"
 },
 {
   "first_name": "fname2",
   "last_name": "lname2",
   "city_name": "paris",
   "Address": "1st Ave"
 }
 .
 .
 .
]
```

and my fields in JsonObject is dynamic so i can't use a class with predefined fields , so i've decided to use Map to parse the Json response as below :

```
Collection<List<Map<String,String>>> list_Objects = null;
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<List<Map<String,String>>>>(){}.getType();
list_objects = gson.fromJson(reader, collectionType);
```

but it throws me this error :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

im not expert in Json parsing so please tell me where is my mistake or if there is another way to implement such behavior i would be very appreciated.

Comment: The `map` expects an array, like the one you provide for the begin-end list with `[ ]`. What you have in `JSON` is a list of objects, not a list of Maps

Comment: Try some information here [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20801029/1636209)

Comment: @RaulRene : i can't change the Json response , can you correct my codes or any other way to parse this Json?

Comment: why don't you use a map of map? or just a List of Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `Collection` wrapper on the `List` one.

You just need to define the `list_Objects` as `List<Map<String, String>>`.

I just tried the following with Jackson's `ObjectMapper` (which should work the same as GSON) and it worked ok:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list_objects = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, String>>>(){});
```

The result is a `List` of `LinkedHashMap` objects.

For your `GSON` example, you just need to remove the `Collection<>`, or the `List<>` if you prefer.

Comment: Ty Raul for answer , but i've changed it to: List<Map<String,String>> list_objects = null;  and   Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String,String>>>(){}.getType();  with no success , throws same error

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `GSON`, maybe you could try the above example with jackson to see if that works?

Comment: i'll try that, appreciate your time

Comment: Did it work? Did you find another solution? Consider selecting an answer as the correct one or putting down your own answer if you found  a separate solution

Comment: sorry for late response finally i got it working by checking my url again!!.mistakenly one parameter were missed so the response form webservice was []!! such a stupid misatke ;) but i've used your answer and just used Collection<Map<String, String>>.Ty

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you're defining your list twice.

`Collection<List<Map<String, String>>>` would map to a structure like

`[ [ {"bla": "bla"}, {"bla": "bla"} ], [ {"foo": "bar"}, ... ], ... ]`

(because List is a kind of Collection). So, try using `List<Map<String, String>>` and see if that works...